# How can I remove all array elements that have duplicates, leaving only single values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I store only elements that are individual values?

Example :

```sh
> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'a', 'd'] // this
> ['c', 'e'] // to this
```

Anyone can help me about this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate values from JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compare first found index of element with the last one, and filter array based on those

```js
const data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'a', 'd'];
const result = data.filter(element => data.indexOf(element) === data.lastIndexOf(element))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with O(n) using `reduce` and `filter`.

```js
var data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'a', 'd']

let map = data.reduce((a,c) => (a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1,a),{}),
    res = Object.keys(map).filter(e => map[e] == 1);

console.log(res)
```

First we create a map of the elements by using `reduce`, counting how often they appear in the array as value for each element's key. Afterwards we take the keys with `Object.keys` and apply `filter`, keeping only those keys where the value is exactly 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and algorithmic approach:**

In the first iteration, the count of each element is being stored as key-value pairs (The key is the actual **element** and the **count** being the value).

If the element is already in the object, we increment its count otherwise we store it with a count of 1.

In the second iteration, we push all those elements **whose count is exactly 1** to a new array.

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'a', 'd']
var repeating = {};
a.map(_ => {
  if(_ in repeating) {
    repeating[_] += 1;
  } else {
    repeating[_] = 1;
  }
})

let nonRepeating = [];

for(var key in repeating) {
  if(repeating[key] == 1) {
    nonRepeating.push(key);
  }
}

console.log(nonRepeating)
```

Comment: Some inline documentation would go a long way here. This isn't exactly intuitive code.